# Issue with should.js using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, should.js

My code is:

```
Object.keys(res.body.data).should.containEql('id')
```

The error that TypeScript gives me is

```
Property 'should' does not exist on type 'string[]'.
```

So how do I use `should` with TypeScript?

Comment: Let me know if my answer fixed your problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the import of should library. Basically you need to import `import 'should'` to have access to should methods.

I have tested this code and it works! If I comment the import I had the same issue that you have.

```
import 'should';

describe('test', () => {

    it('should must work', () => {
        Object.keys({ a: 1, b: 2 }).should.containEql('b');
    })
})
```

Comment: This doesn’t compile for me (TypeScript 2.9.2).

Comment: Have you installed the definitions? `npm install @types/should @types/mocha --save-dev`

Comment: Ah, I didn’t realize this was running under Mocha. Now it works. Nice!